# terraform plan fails with time out after 5 min

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I have a terraform script to run from Github action.
Terraform version : 0.12.6 which we are planning to upgrade.
It contains various modules for AWS Neptune database, Helm Releases to deploy on EKS.

While the pipeline runs for terraform validate stage, it fails at terraform plan stage.
After 38 refershing state log lines, it always gets stuck and times out after 5 min.

log lines like : aws_neptune_parameter_group.main: Refreshing state... [id=XYZ]

Error :
**Error: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Running' (last state: 'Pending', timeout: 5m0s)**

There isn't any time out set in scripts.
The last log line is not the same (not for the same resource) everytime.

Usually for last 3 min, no log gets printed and it gets timed out at 5.

I enabled TRACE log for terraform, but nothing is getting printed which can give an idea.

Can you please suggest how should the troubleshooting be done next?

Comment: Can you perform the same actions locally, without using GitHub actions?

Comment: A provider waiting for a state change during the _refresh_ operation is quite unusual, since refresh is supposed to reconcile Terraform's records with the remote system and not actually change the remote system. I suggest opening a bug report in [the AWS provider repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws) so the provider maintainers can investigate.

Comment: It also isn't clear from your question exactly which resource encountered this error. Was there any other information after this error message about which resource the error was generated for?

Comment: Hello all, thank you for your suggestions.
It looks like a problem with a helm release (neptune proxy).
The helm version is 2 and provider is also quite old.
Also, the release is missing when we list all helm releases.

I have to move to an urgent task for few days.
But, will update here about the further information.

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning resources such as EKS clusters and neptune parameter group takes a little bit longer compared to other resources like S3 buckets. In order to ensure that Terraform does not timeout within five minutes, please add the following node inside your `aws_neptune_parameter_group` resource block

```
  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }
```

If your resource got stuck at `refreshing state` status, may you try to delete the state for that resource and re-issue `terraform plan` command again?

```bash
terraform state rm aws_neptune_parameter_group.main
```

Comment: Isn't the issue here during the plan phase?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the actual problem @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

The issue was - there was a neptune proxy release on Helm2 deployed few years back with TF.
Later on, someone had upgraded the Helm version manually.
TF was getting stuck on finding the neptune proxy release.
The GitHub runner was using a container image with Helm2 installed.
There were manual fixes required here.

Thank you for all the suggestions.